# Nagios 4.0.2 Error: Could not open CGI config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/cgi.cfg' for reading

Tags: cgi, nagios

I recently upgraded from Nagios Core 3.2.3 to v 4.0.2. After the upgrade when i browse to WEBGUI of Nagios i get this error when i click on Maps.Other things run fine.

Error is 
Could not open CGI config file '/usr/local/nagios-3.2.3/etc/cgi.cfg' for reading

Note: nagios-3.2.3 was my old file location and now I changed  it to nagios-4.0.2 and now it doesn't work. Is there a way i can point cgi.cfg to new location 
i.e. /usr/local/nagios-4.0.2

Please help

Comment: allready checked permission and owner of file? Would guess it got messed up.

Comment: What files or folders should I check??

Comment: Which files and folders permissions do i need to check??

Answer (score 0):

From http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configcgi.html :

> By default, Nagios expects the CGI configuration file to be named
>   cgi.cfg and located in the config file directory along with the main
>   config file. If you need to change the name of the file or its
>   location, you can configure Apache to **pass an environment variable
>   named NAGIOS_CGI_CONFIG** (which points to the correct location) to
>   the CGIs. See the Apache documentation for information on how to do
>   this.